# Abstract Class and Dependency Injection in Shopware 6, Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, oop, shopware, shopware6

Currently I am working on Shopware 6 extension, which is based on Symfony. What I don’t understand, is how to implement abstract classes and dependency injection.

So I want to be able to refactor the code, and to use those methods often, but in another context (with another repository)

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace WShop\Service;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\EqualsFilter;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Uuid\Uuid;

/**
 * Service for writing Products
 */
class ProductService
{
    private EntityRepository  $productRepository;
    private MediaImageService $mediaImageService;
    private EntityRepository  $productMediaRepository;

    public function __construct(
        EntityRepository  $productRepository,
        MediaImageService $mediaImageService,
        EntityRepository  $productMediaRepository
    )
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->mediaImageService = $mediaImageService;
        $this->productMediaRepository = $productMediaRepository;
    }

private function createProduct(array $data, Context $context = null): void
{
    $context = $context ?? Context::createDefaultContext();

    $this->productRepository->create([
                                         $data
                                     ], $context);
}

public function updateProduct(array $data): void
{
    $this->productRepository->update([$data], Context::createDefaultContext());
}

public function getExistingProductId(string $productNumber): ?string
{
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('productNumber', $productNumber));

    return $this->productRepository->searchIds($criteria, 
     Context::createDefaultContext())->firstId();
 }
}
```

As you can see, there are dependency injection inside construct (Product Repository). Now my question is, how am I able to create abstract class, that is storing those methods, but the child classes is going to kind of "rewrite" parent construct with repository that is needed? For example, I want to use **getDataId** (Now it is called getExistingProductId, but it is going to be refactored and renamed in abstract class) method on **product repository**, but for the next class I want to use the same method on **categors repository**?

Service.xml aka Dependency Injector

```
<service id="wshop_product_service" class="WShop\Service\ProductService">
            <argument type="service" id="product.repository"/>
            <argument id="wshop_media_image_service" type="service"/>
            <argument type="service" id="product_media.repository"/>
</service>
```

I am kind of new into OOP. Please provide good example and code explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you just want the first argument to be interchangeable and the 3 methods in your example should be implemented in the abstract. Here's one idea for that.

The abstract:

```php
abstract class AbstractEntityService
{
    protected EntityRepository $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepository  $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function create(array $data, ?Context $context = null): void
    {
        $context = $context ?? Context::createDefaultContext();

        $this->repository->create([
            $data
        ], $context);
    }

    public function update(array $data): void
    {
        $this->repository->update([$data], Context::createDefaultContext());
    }
    
    abstract public function getDataId(array $params): ?string;

    protected function searchId(Criteria $criteria): ?string
    {
        return $this->repository->searchIds(
            $criteria,
            Context::createDefaultContext()
        )->firstId();
    }
}
```

You take the repository in the constructor and implement all your general methods regarding the generic repositories in the abstract. The `getDataId` method you want to implement in the extending class, since you use a specific criteria for each one (presumably). So you just force the implementation in the extending class by defining an abstract signature.

Your service class:

```php
class ProductService extends AbstractEntityService
{
    private MediaImageService $mediaImageService;

    private EntityRepository $productMediaRepository;

    public function __construct(
        EntityRepository $productRepository,
        MediaImageService $mediaImageService,
        EntityRepository $productMediaRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct($productRepository);
        $this->mediaImageService = $mediaImageService;
        $this->productMediaRepository = $productMediaRepository;
    }

    public function getDataId(array $params): ?string
    {
        if (!isset($params['productNumber'])) {
            return null;
        }

        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('productNumber', $params['productNumber']));

        return $this->searchId($criteria);
    }

    // your other methods using the injected services
}
```

In the extending class you pass only the repository to the parent constructor since the other injected services are used only in this specific instance. You implement `getDataId` where you create your specific criteria and call the protected (since it should only be used by extensions) `searchId` method with the criteria.